# Exclude an array in a LINQ expression that connects to CRM

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2017, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to run a LINQ query that gets all objects of a specific type [new_contact], but filters out those with a specific field value [new_identifier] that matches in a list [excludeIdentifiers].

```
public static List<new_placement>ActivityCounter(Account account, CRM2011DataContext CRMcontext)
{
    int[] excludedIdentifiers = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 19, 20, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45 };
    var myActivities = (from a in CRMcontext.new_placementSet
                             where
                             !(a.new_entity_identifier.Value.Equals(excludedIdentifiers))
                                 select new new_placement() { ActivityId = a.ActivityId }).ToList();
        return myActivities;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 occurred
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message=Condition for attribute 'new_placement.new_entity_identifier': expected argument(s) of type 'System.Int32' but received 'System.Int32[]'.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
StackTrace:<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

I am certain that the error is caused by the fifth line (because it runs through fine without it):

```
!(a.new_entity_identifier.Value.Equals(excludedIdentifiers))
```

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and CRM 2016 on premise and Windows 10. Google returns me answers that are at least seven years old, not concrete enough and not working for me.

Answer (score 5):

The error message describes your problem exactly, you are trying to compare an **Int** value to an **array of** **Int**.

You need to change the line `!(a.new_entity_identifier.Value.Equals(excludedIdentifiers))`

to something like `!excludedIdentifiers.Contains(a.new_entity_identifier.Value)`

Comment: I was just informed by my colleagues that Linq cannot use the Contains method with CRM.

Comment: Why? Is there ambiguity between Enumerable.Contains and Entity.Contains?

Comment: @ToFo I don't understand why there would be such a limitation. Perhaps I misunderstood the comment but the .Contains() method is called on the Array/List/Enumerable and CRM should have no effect on it.

Comment: @JanusPienaar except that this is a LINQ to SQL query, which get's translated into a Query Expression, and performed on the server and then returned.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in a more 'manual' fashion. Its neither pretty or flexible but it works.

```
public static List<new_placement>ActivityCounter(Account account, CRM2011DataContext CRMcontext)
{
var myActivities = (from a in CRMcontext.new_placementSet
                         where
                         a.new_entity_identifier.Value != 6
                         a.new_entity_identifier.Value != 7
                         a.new_entity_identifier.Value != 8
                         a.new_entity_identifier.Value != 9 // And so on..
                             select new new_placement() { ActivityId = a.ActivityId }).ToList();
    return myActivities;
}
```

Comment: I also ended up doing it this ugly way. Does anyone see a better solution?